# Line wrap cuts off inline element border

Tags: html, css

I have a list of inline elements with padding and borders. When one element wraps, the last element of the previous line gets its border cut off.

Html:

```
<div class="multi-select">
  <div class="selected-list">
    <span class="selected-item">aankoop;boodschap;koop <span class="remove-choice fa fa-close"></span></span>
    <span class="selected-item">accessoire <span class="remove-choice fa fa-close"></span></span>
    <span class="selected-item">afmeting <span class="remove-choice fa fa-close"></span></span>
    <span class="selected-item">aantal;tal <span class="remove-choice fa fa-close"></span></span>
    <span class="selected-item">accu;batterij <span class="remove-choice fa fa-close"></span></span>
    <span class="selected-item">afwerking <span class="remove-choice fa fa-close"></span></span>
    <span class="selected-item">adapter <span class="remove-choice fa fa-close"></span></span>
    <span class="selected-item">one more item to make this stuff wrap <span class="remove-choice fa fa-close"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.selected-list {
  border: 1px #cacaca solid;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  min-height: 3.4375rem;
  line-height: calc(2.4375rem - 2px);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.selected-item {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 255);
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  border: 1px blue solid;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.remove-choice {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]
https://jsfiddle.net/346wdoyw/1/

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

The `<span>` tag is `display:inline` by default, it gets rendered like a sentence, just like the plain text.

> How can I fix it?

Set it to `display:inline-block`, it's more like a `block` but also `inline`, it's displayed as a ground of sentences. It also respects `width`/`height`, `padding`/`margin` correctly.

You can do more tests with/without `white-space:nowrap` to see the differences more clearly.

```
.selected-item {
  display: inline-block;
  ...
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/346wdoyw/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
.selected-item {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0.1rem; // modify this as per your needs..
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0; // modify this as per your needs..
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for showing adjustements need to be made. I also had to set line-height to account for my borders in order to get the same result as before.

Comment: yes, line-height was also necessary to change, i agree with you)