# How to fix breaking border when text cannot fit in the container

Tags: html, css

How can I avoid this happening?

[image: viz1]

I tried with responsive font-size based on viewport width & height but it didn't worked as expected.

I also tried to make the container width larger so it can fit but still if the domain name is larger enough it will cause the same problem

Here is the code:

```css
.link_border {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: .7px;
  border: 1px solid #777777;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" class="link_border">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-globe me-1"></i> Visit stackoverflow.com
</a>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't exhibit this behaviour. Please edit the snippet to show what you are describing.

Comment: @LeeTaylor It reproduces for me when the window is the correct size, I've edited in an increased font size so it should reproduce by default in the snippet viewer.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Everyone knows that when you put an element with border inside a bootstrap column for example and the text become larger than the column the text is breaking and the border is bugging. What else should I explain?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line wrap cuts off inline element border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550662/line-wrap-cuts-off-inline-element-border) (TLDR: Use `display: inline-block`)